# Cant read count(*) value in temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fill a temporary table with values from another table and a count value, but it always throws the error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
> definition

My code looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE  #TempTable
([ObjectId] uniqueidentifier, [ListName] nvarchar(255), [HowMany] int)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT [ObjectId]
      ,[ListName]
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ATable] as a WHERE [ObjectId] = a.FK_ObjectId ) AS [HowMany]
FROM [AnotherTable]
```

It works fine for the other columns but not for the [HowMany] column.
I already tried to cast the SELECT count(*) to an integer but that also did not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `DROP`ing your table, `#TempTable`, in a batch *prior* to the above query; does that solve the problem? If you're on a recent version of SQL Server, then you can use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`.

Comment: What value are you trying to insert into the ObjectId col?

Comment: The command works fine for me, after creating the tables & adding some data. Are you sure it's this part where the problem is?

Comment: Creating and using a temp table in a single batch is a bad idea, due to the complicated way that deferred compilation and name resolution works. In general, creating a table and immediately using (without ending the batch and beginning a new one) isn't guaranteed to work; when it does work it's more by accident than design. From SSMS, make it a habit to put a `GO` after DDL statements; from client code, submit things as separate statements. If you're using temp tables inside stored procedures, where this isn't possible, be very mindful of the scope of the tables.

Comment: yeah, running only this portion of the code doesn't throw an error like that. Either you already created the temp table with other columns (as @Larnu is implying) or the error is in another place

Comment: Tried again and found that a batch run in SSMS shows only the *last error*. If the CREATE fails, then it proceeds with the INSERT, even if there is not a GO in between. If the INSERT also fails then you see only the error from the INSERT, not from the failed CREATE. See the other comments for how to solve.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I used DROP TABLE IF EXISTS, just did not put that in code. 
And actually inserted Code I selected from some JOINT Tables. Maby the Problem lies in there.

Comment: I solved the problem now by first changing [HowMany] into a nvarchar(255) and inserting [ListName], then changing it back to int and inserting the number 4 and then changed 4 again in the SELECT count(*) statement to get the same code as I started with..
But now it works.....
WTF

Answer (score 0):

I'm checking your request, I think that query below will help you, take a look please, I didn't use a temp table but is just the update the table names to be able to use a temp table.

As you didn't show us the structure of your table, I also made an example to make it simpler to understand, I think :-).

```
DECLARE @Category as table (
  id int,
  category nvarchar(50)
);

DECLARE @Product as table (
  id int,
  idCategory int,
  productName nvarchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @Category
VALUES 
    (1, 'Category 1'),
    (2, 'Category 2'),
    (3, 'Category 3')

INSERT INTO @Product
VALUES 
    (1,1, 'Product 1'),
    (2,1, 'Product 2'),
    (3,1, 'Product 3'),
    (4,2, 'Product 4'),
    (5,2, 'Product 5'),
    (6,2, 'Product 6'),
    (7,2, 'Product 7'),
    (8,2, 'Product 8'),
    (9,3, 'Product 9'),
    (10,3, 'Product 10'),
    (11,3, 'Product 11'),
    (12,3, 'Product 12')

    --To know how many product is used by category
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            C.*,
            (Count(P.id) over (partition by C.ID order by C.category)) as HowManyProductByCategory
        FROM 
            @Category as C
        INNER JOIN @Product as P ON C.id = P.idCategory
    ) as T
    GROUP BY T.id, T.category, T.HowManyProductByCategory
```

The result

```
id  category    HowManyProductByCategory
1   Category 1  3
2   Category 2  5
3   Category 3  4
```

Best Regards

Comment: The comments made it rather certain that the problem was in the `CREATE TempTable` being done when `#TempTable` already existed (but with different columns), combined with not using GO which made that problem invisible.